# Trigger OmniFaces multi field validation after focus lost

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

I need to create a validation on Calendar components - Begin/End. OmniFaces supports multi field validation very well, like here:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">

    <h:outputLabel for="startDate" value="Start date" />
    <h:inputText id="startDate" value"#{booking.reservation.startDate}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Please enter start date"
        converterMessage="Please enter format yyyy-MM-dd">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="startDate" />

    <h:outputLabel for="endDate" value="End date" />
    <h:inputText id="endDate" value"#{booking.reservation.endDate}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Please enter end date"
        converterMessage="Please enter format yyyy-MM-dd">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:message for="endDate" />
        <h:message for="order" />
        <o:validateOrder id="order" components="startDate endDate" 
            message="End date must be after start date" />
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGrid>

<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{booking.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But, In this example validation is triggered after manually submit. And I need to validate after focus (of Calendar) is lost. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The multi field validators from OmniFaces can be referenced in `<f:ajax execute>`. The "focus lost" event is the `blur` event. Thus, this should do:

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="startDate endDate order" render="m_startDate m_endDate m_order" />
</h:inputText>
```

where `m_startDate`, etc are the IDs of the `<h:message>` components like so

```
<h:message id="m_startDate" for="startDate" />
```